# Voice to text java application with Dragon(DNS) API

Tags: jakarta-ee, bluedragon

I am using Dragon's software for my application to transform voice into text.Based on voice command I want to execute specific function from my script, I have search lot but did not found how to integrate Dragon's API with application. I have also looked at dragons site which has section for developer guide.Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purchaced the SDK you have access to the Dragon NaturallySpeaking Developer Support Program. They should be able to give you all the support you need to get started.

> The Dragon NaturallySpeaking SDK Client Edition
>   (DSC) provides developers with tools, including
>   the Dragon APIs, to integrate speech recognition
>   capabilities into applications. When programming
>   in the DSC environment, developers access Dragon’s
>   ActiveX controls using the Dragon APIs. Developers
>   can program in any language that ActiveX
>   control supports. However, officially supported
>   environments include Visual Basic , C# and Visual
>   C++.
>
> **Comprehensive sample code and detailed documentation is available.**
>
> In addition, the Dragon NaturallySpeaking Developer Support Program offers:
>
> - Direct answers to development questions from Dragon Developer Support engineers via Web form or telephone
> - Access to Dragon NaturallySpeaking SDK TechNotes and FAQs
> - Access to software updates as they become available for in-house testing and prototyping